# How to make old instance of Linux process exit when I launch new one?

Tags: c++, linux, process, exit

I write executable for Linux in C++. I wounder how to make old instance of Linux process exit when I launch new process? Thanks.

Comment: How about having the new one kill the old one so the old one doesn't have to keep looking to see if a new one has started?

Answer (score 0):

The process can write its PID to a file. When the new instance starts up, it should read the file, and then kill the process with that PID. Then it writes its own PID to the file.

When the process exits normally, it should truncate or remove the file, so the next instance won't try to kill it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

When the app starts have it create a file with the process ID. When the new instance starts, query that process id and kill it.